Horror movie about a demon (or telekinetic ?) boy who kills his family members
There was a film I saw a few scenes of sometime during the early to mid 90s. 
I just remember a short scene but I think the scene is unique enough for someone to be able to identify it.
It had a small boy (I think he was in class or something, but he was with other adults; I think they were a man and a woman but I'm not sure). He had a hand drawn crayon picture of his family (I think; it might have been a foster family), a man, woman, a girl and a boy, and he had crossed out the woman in the picture with red (I think) crayon, which the adults around him notice as well.
In the next scene we see the woman in the kitchen, and and from a camera angle as if we are seeing her from the point of view of a dog (is there a name for this angle?). She looks at the camera, acts spooked and starts walking backwards. Then she screams and falls backwards on a pipe protruding out of the wall. It's implied that the pipe went through her skull and out her mouth, because in the next scene we see water coming out her of mouth, which soon turns from clear to a dark red.
This scene scared the hell out of me at the time so I am sure I didn't just imagine it. What movie was this?  
Edit:  
I remember seeing the film in English and most likely it was American  

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

What colour hair did the woman have?. I've seen this scene. I can't place it though. Yet

@Darren: sorry can't remember. Probably blond or brown, and I think it was shoulder length. She was wearing a checkered (or similar type of colourful) shirt, but I really can't be sure about any of those details
